# TP Link router behind another router and google services difficulties

Tags: networking, router

I have a configuration with a TP-Link router behind my FAI provider router (Freebox Mini) as the FAI router wifi cannot handle a lot of devices.

My TP-Link has a fix IP configured as a DMZ access, with a subnet 192.168.1.1/24. My FAI router have a subnet of 192.168.0.1/24.

Everything is fine except some Google services. Sometime some YouTube video doesn't work, I cannot download Apps from google store.

Everything works when I connect to the Wi-Fi of my FAI router.

The MTU on my TP-Link is 1500, but I cannot tell if it is the same on the FAI router. I do not think ther is any firwall on the router level.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: We will need more info please. At least the subnets of the two routers, the important IP addresses. Is the firewall on, on the TP-Link (if so try turning it off to see if that helps, then we have a clue if it is that), are your MTU settings the same on both routers (TP-Link should match the other for safety).  Any other details you can give would be helpful. Is the reason you are using a 2nd router pertenant?  There are other things it could be, but this would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the original post with some details.

Comment: What are the IPv6 support settings of both routers? Does each of them have IPv6 addresses on the WAN interface and on the LAN side? And, because the subnets are separate, do the routers have different Wi-Fi SSIDs as well?

Comment: They are booth configured to use IPv4. The two routers have a different SSID